# how to navigate a large OpenAPI schema with enums and formats

Tags: api, swagger, postman, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a large OpenApi schema I need view & understand.  Perhaps I'm just missing something but neither `Postman` or `SwaggerUI` make this easy.  `class`es (`"type":"object"`s) are handled OK - but other critical elements do not have their details displayed:

- `format`s do not display

  - `{"type":"string", "format":"uuid"}` --> just displays as `{"type":"string"}`
- `enums` don't display their values, or even that it is an `enum` 'type'.

By "large" I mean a few thousand lines of `yaml` in the spec, a couple hundred types, etc.  Sure, one can navigate the `yaml` directly ... but this completely negates the purpose of the graphical interface, and is incredibly slow for a large document.

here's a screenshot from `SwaggerUI`.  I would expect the `AnEnum` schema to show that it's an enum, and it's values; and `AClass.single_nested.a_list` is a list of `uuid`s ... with only `string` it's not helpful.  Postman isn't any better; it generates example data, which *does* fill in `uuid`s with a valid UUID; but values for `enum`s are just ~`lorem ipsum` (ie actually invalid, despite Postman having access to the enum values)

[image: full schema below]

Don't love the wall of text, but here's the yaml that generated this.

```
components:
  schemas:
    AnEum:
      description: An enumeration.

              ###############
      enum:   ############### <- nothing useful is shown for enums
      - foo
      - bar
      title: AnEum
    AnotherClass:
      properties:
        a_list:
          items:
            type: string
            format: uuid
          title: A List
          type: array
      required:
      - a_list
      title: AnotherClass
      type: object
    AClass:
      properties:
        single_nested:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AnotherClass'
        an_enum:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AnEum'
        ## lots and lots
      required:
      - an_enum
      - single_nested
      title: AClass
      type: object
  securitySchemes:
    BearerTokenAuth:
      bearerFormat: JWT
      scheme: bearer
      type: http
info:
  description: 'dump a quick example'
  title: demo full schema 2
  version: 0.0.1
openapi: 3.0.2
paths:
  /api/v12345/somepath/{id_in_path}/:
    get:
      description: '...'
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/AClass'
          description: success
          ## lots and lots
      security:
      - BearerTokenAuth: []
      summary: none
    parameters:
    - description: the id_in_path as a UUID.
      in: path
      name: id_in_path
      required: true
      schema:

                        #########
        format: uuid    #########  <---  format not shown graphically
        type: string
```

Any graphical tool that displays the "full" schema graphically would be fine; the primary necessary feature is the same as why an IDE has 'go-to-definintion'.  SwaggerUI's "expandable" formatted tree works, too (if it had the information)

Comment: https://editor.swagger.io/ did you try this to validate the schema

Comment: yes, this was simplified from a large (valid) openapi3 spec.  @hellen's answer below is correct, there is a not-yet-shipped bug in `Swagger UI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swagger UI schema view, the `format` is displayed in parentheses after the type name. For example, `type: string` + `format: uuid` is displayed as `string($uuid)`.

[image: Schema 'format' in Swagger UI]

Enum values not being displayed is a [bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6906) that only affects enums without an explicit `type`. This bug will be fixed in the next release of Swagger UI/Editor. The workaround is to add the `type` to the enum:

```yaml
    AnEum:
      type: string   # <------------
      description: An enumeration.
      enum:
      - foo
      - bar
      title: AnEum
```

Comment: I had noticed the `$uuid` text - was hoping there was a better way (especially since postman seems to have a similar ~issue in not clearly showing it's a UUID

Comment: however, your bug link for swagger is correct, and this was the real blocker (since _nothing_ for enums was shown).  Answer accepted, thank you.